# Removing row for results of mysql query python but not deleting from database

Tags: python, mysql, geolocation

I'm developing an application which needs to use distance calculated between two zipcodes to determine whether or not that row is displayed to the user or not. If the distance is not greater than 100 miles, the result is to remain in result set returned from the sql query, however if it is greater than 100 I want to remove it from the result set but leave it in the sql table

```
def zipcode(offerzip, techzip):
    dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance('us')
    distance = dist.query_postal_code(offerzip, techzip)
    distance = distance/1.609
    return round(distance)

def techOffer()
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status='offer'",)
    offerData = cur.fetchall()
    result_2 = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s", [session['username']])
    techData = cur.fetchall()
    techZip = techData['zip']
    for row in offerData:
         offerZip = offerData['zip']
         if zipcode(offerZip, techZip) !< 100:
```

Output of print(techData):

```
({'id': 20, 'name': 'Sage Hopkins', 'email': 'Removed', 'username': 'sagefhopkins', 'password': '$5$rounds=535000$KywbJzy7Oo6lNfrJ$iz9BPUcLF.2HUttL8zRZVEIcwJ8/O3RxOkWZH0lsdO1', 'street': 'Removed ', 'city': 'Removed', 'state': 'Removed', 'zip': 97537, 'phone': 'Removed', 'cell': 'Removed', 'permission': None, 'register_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 27, 20, 29, 26)},)
```

Output of print(offerData):

```
({'id': 7, 'userid': 20, 'assignedid': 20, 'name': 'Sage Hopkins', 'email': 'Removed', 'phone': 'Removed', 'street': 'Removed', 'city': 'REmoved', 'state': 'Removed', 'country': 'United States', 'zip': '80906', 'issue': 'Very major computer issue, Very major computer issue, Very major computer issue, Very major computer issue, Very major computer issue, ', 'support_Type': 'Home', 'computer': 'Dell T700', 'operating_System': 'Windows', 'status': 'offer', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 27, 20, 30, 43)},)
```

Comment: What row are you trying to exclude?  It doesn't look like `distance` is a database column.

Comment: Distance isn't in a database column, however zip codes for order data, and techData are. **zipcode(offerzip, techzip)** is used to calculate the distance between the two zipcodes. **techOffer()** function then processes SQL queries for active "offers" and uses the zipcode function in order to calculate the distance between the two zip codes, if that distance isn't greater than 100 I want to remove the row from the dataset

Comment: What package are you using to connect to MySQL?

Comment: **flask_mysqldb**

Comment: I should be able to give you an answer, but I am not familiar with that package, and the [docs](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_mysqldb.MySQL) for  it don't show you what the result data looks like.  Can you add an update showing the results of `print(techData)`?

Comment: @CalebGoodman I updated the post to include an output of techData, also I'm pretty sure **mysql-connector** is the relevant package for **flask_mysqldb**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `del` keyword to delete keys from dictionaries.  In your case, you need to iterate over results, since it is a *tuple of dictionaries*:

```
if zipcode(offerZip, techZip) <= 100:
    for obj in techData:
        del obj['zip']

    for obj in offerData:
        del obj['zip']
```

**Note** that this has no affect whatsoever on data in your database, and only changes the instances of `techData` and `offerData`.

Also, I don't think `!<` is valid syntax.  Use `<=` for *less than or equal to* and `<` for *less than*.